# text padding inside a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm creating a dashboard and I want to make a padding of the text inside the Button, so the text begins after the icon. I tried all padding options over the Button, but no result. The padding ones move the entry Button. Also, the spacing options where disappointing, because they control the space between lines, not the space inside the button.

Is there a way to locate the text of the Buttons after the icon?
Any idea or approach would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the idea of the what I want as Button's background.
[image: Button style for dashboard]

Comment: Have you tried setting the gravity to the center?

Comment: I wouldnt do a button... i would do an <a>.  It would look nicer as you can do something like <a class = 'buttonItem'><img src="...">Some Text</a>

Comment: yes I tried gravity center, nut the idea is that the text starts exactly after the icon, because the texts are of different sizes.

Comment: @PedroTeran You can create a function that add spaces to your text depends on image's width & height. It's not the best, but could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this easily with a 9-patch image.

Have a look at some [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)(more [tutorials](http://blog.fenrir-inc.com/us/2012/02/android-design-enlarge-images-with-nine-patch.html)) to discover its power.

Take this 9-patch image:

[image]

Set it as your button's background. Then just write some text and the image will adapt to your text's length. In case you want the button to be of a certain width, just set a fixed width and your text will break into lines.

EDIT: When you download the image save it with a name like `button_icon.9.png`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a CompoundDrawable.
They are ment just for this case. You basically have a TextView and set the view to the left to be your icon. Not only does this do what you want, but you also eliminate another view on the screen.

Check out
[setDrawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft)

Basically you can use

```
android:drawableLeft
```

or

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)
```

Comment: Cool. This method takes in the Resource ids and 0 if there isn't one. But there are some other different ones too.

Comment: was a good option, but it doesn't make the drawable fit as planned, so I'm not sure if this will be compatible with all screen sizes

Comment: Well if you want to support all screen sizes, you need to make it a 9-patch